# Spring Data JPA / OpenJPA: Is there an equivalent to SQL !=-Operator

Tags: java, spring, jpa, openjpa

Is there an equivalent to the native sql !=-operator for Spring Data JPA @Query-Annotation using OpenJPA? So i thought it would work somewhat like this:

```
@Query("select a from TableA a, TableB b where a.property != b.property")
```

but it doesn't, or lets say at least my ide (intellij) shows me that it does not know how to work with '!='.

The (as i thought) corresponding

```
@Query("select a from TableA, TableB b where a.property = b.property")
```

works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JPQL you should use SQL syntax (for the most part) meaning that `!=` is expressed with `<>`. See also [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Operators)

Comment: just found the corresponding part here: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.1.1/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html (if anyone sarchs for more insight, chapters 2.5.5 and on), but thanks anyway! I didn't find the documentation-site, so I asked here. It's early in the morning here ;) will accept your answer when I can (7 min.)